# A LINQ query for corresponding SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Basicall I have three Tables Users Roles and USerRoles with Many to many Relationship and also Department Table. So when I import these on .edmx i get only two Entities. so i have Navigation Properties in both Entities. I have three Users and 2 Roles (admin and ReadOnly). . Below is my Sql Query[image: Entity Diagram]

```
select U.UserName,r.RoleName,dp.DepName
from Users U
inner join UserRoles UR on U.UseID = UR.UserId
inner join Roles r on UR.RoleId = r.RoleID
inner join dbo.Department Dp on dp.DepId = U.DepId
group by r.RoleName,U.UserName,Dp.DepName
```

This is my Linq Query i tried I am able to Get depName but not RoleName for particular User.
        Actually there is Many to many relationship between User roles and UerRoles. In my Context i don have UserRoles Entity.Please help me on this.

```
List<User> user = db.Users.Include("Department,Roles").ToList(); 
foreach (var U in user)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(U.UseID + " " + U.UserName +" "+ U.Department.DepName+ " "+ U.Roles.);            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as you have Many-to-Many relationship you need to iterate over each role of each user:

```
foreach (var u in users)
{
    foreach (var r on u.Roles)
    {
        Comsole.WriteLine("User {0} has role {1}, u.UserName, r.RoleName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks But still i am unable to get the RoleName from Roles Collections.

Comment: No error,But I am unable to access RoleName. where as I am to print DepName for each user...AutoGenerated User Entity with Roles Roles Property  public TrackableCollection<Role> Roles Do i need to make Property as Virtual

Comment: Yah thanks a lot its working..By the way i am new to Entity framework an linq query so i was doing some R&D....R u wroking on EF

Comment: Well In this scenario is it better to keep Many to many Relationship..or we can store Role id in user Table. Which would be better.

Comment: @MutturajBali: Do you have plans to add user to multiple roles? If this is prohibited by design, you may want to switch to One-to-One relationship, so you will have just `user.Role.RoleName`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13357/discussion-between-mutturaj-bali-and-abatishchev)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 1 include per table. Your query should look like this

```
List<User> users = db.Users.Include("Department").Include("Roles").ToList();
```